# best practice to save main state (users, server lists, etc.) on a react app?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm developing a react app for a long time and is working ok and fast.
It's a big interface with a lot of server data. I need a better state management to debug better my app.

I'm wondering about migrating to Redux for main state, or take a middle approach and encapsulate main state (user login, server entities lists, menus, etc.) outside any react component.

Rigth now all my state is contained into react main component (Layout component, that render all other visual components inside it), and state items are spraying down the tree as props for subcomponents that need them.

I don't find any docs about best practices on state management on big react apps, please give me some idea or links.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

read this discussion https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/redux-and-global-state-vs-local-state/4187/15 on what state must be local to components (most agree on consider local state what don't must be known by other components or server) and what must be global and passed as props to components to render.

Also read http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state and change redux for your preferred global state container